# How to make fetch request and get data from object in python?

Tags: python, api

Can someone help me please. I am doing fetch request and trying to get data using python. But I am getting an error.

```js
import requests
import json 

response_API = requests.get('https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?q=sports&country=ru&pageSize=10&apiKey=befce9fd53c04bb695e30568399296c0')
print(response_API.status_code)

data=response_API.text

parse_json=json.loads(response_API)

active_case=parse_json['name']
print('Total results',active_case)
```

I'm trying to get the `name` from the following array:

```
{"status":"ok","totalResults":2,"articles":[{"source":{"id":null,"**name**":"Sports.ru"},"author":"Валерий Левкин","title":"Леброн Джеймс получил «Золотую малину» за худшую актерскую работу - Sports.ru","description":"В США названы обладатели антинаграды «Золотая малина» по итогам 2021 года.","url":"https://www.sports.ru/basketball/1107870293-lebron-dzhejms-poluchil-zolotuyu-malinu-za-xudshuyu-akterskuyu-rabotu.html%22,%22urlToImage%22:%22https://www.sports.ru/dynamic_images/news/110/787/029/3/share/bd571e.jpg%22,%22publishedAt%22:%222022-03-26T13:03:00Z%22,%22content":null}]}
```

Got error, value is not returned.

Comment: You have to start from the very top level: `parse_json['articles']` gives you an array. Then you need to go from there.

Comment: @Roksana, you can remove the API KEY from the question if you got the answer. Otherwise, your API requests quota can be exceeded the limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The newsapi URL returns JSON content with a list of articles, where each article has this structure:

```json
{
    "source": {
        "id": null,
        "name": "Sports.ru"
    },
    "author": "...",
    "title": "... - Sports.ru",
    "description": "...",
    "url": "https://www.sports.ru/basketball/1107870293-lebron-dzhejms-poluchil-zolotuyu-malinu-za-xudshuyu-akterskuyu-rabotu.html",
    "urlToImage": "https://www.sports.ru/dynamic_images/news/110/787/029/3/share/bd571e.jpg",
    "publishedAt": "2022-03-26T13:03:00Z",
    "content": null
}
```

To extract a particular element such as description from each article then try this:

```python
import requests
import json 

response = requests.get('https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?q=sports&country=ru&pageSize=10&apiKey=befce9fd53c04bb695e30568399296c0')
print(response.status_code)

response.encoding = "utf-8"
data = response.json()

# to get the name from source of each article
print([article["source"].get("name") for article in data["articles"]])

# to get the descriptions from each article
# where desc will be a list of descriptions
desc = [article["description"] for article in data["articles"]]
print(desc)
```

**Output:**

```
200
['Sports.ru', 'Sports.ru']
['description1', 'description2']
```

Comment: Oh thank you, and can you tell please how do I get the description?

Comment: @Roksana updated code to fetch description.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! The last question, how can I make it not as object, without brackets?

Comment: see update. assign list comphrension expression to a variable.

Comment: It's just returning the text in brackets( How can I make it without them?

Comment: it's a list, if want each item then iterate over the list such as `for d in desc: print(d)`

Comment: @Roksana To understand more what CodeMonkey describes here, you should read about dictionaries and lists in python. These are fundamental data structures that are important to understand if you are going to continue programming.

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow the nesting of objects:

1. First get the key `'articles'`
2. Then get the first element of the list
3. Then get the key `'source'`
4. Finally get the key `'name'`.

You can do this all in a single line with indexes.

Answer (score 0):

slightly different method, but same result using your original technique as the basis.  You get a json string, then convert that to json, then search for the bit that you want.

```py
import requests
import json 

response_API = requests.get('https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?q=sports&country=ru&pageSize=10&apiKey=befce9fd53c04bb695e30568399296c0')
print(response_API.status_code)

# this is a json string
data=response_API.text

# convert string to json
parse_json=json.loads(data)

print('here is the json....')
print(parse_json)

# get an element form json
active_case=parse_json['articles'][0]

# print the result
print('here is the active case...')
print(active_case)
```

This is the result, from which you can extract what you like from it:

```
{'source': {'id': None, 'name': 'Sports.ru'}, 'author': 'Валерий Левкин', 'title': 'Леброн Джеймс получил «Золотую малину» за худшую актерскую работу - Sports.ru', 'description': 'В США названы обладатели антинаграды «Золотая малина» по итогам 2021 года.', 'url': 'https://www.sports.ru/basketball/1107870293-lebron-dzhejms-poluchil-zolotuyu-malinu-za-xudshuyu-akterskuyu-rabotu.html', 'urlToImage': 'https://www.sports.ru/dynamic_images/news/110/787/029/3/share/bd571e.jpg', 'publishedAt': '2022-03-26T13:03:00Z', 'content': None}, {'source': {'id': None, 'name': 'Sports.ru'}, 'author': 'Андрей Карнаухов', 'title': 'Овечкин забил 771-й гол в НХЛ. До Хоу – 30 шайб - Sports.ru', 'description': 'Капитан\xa0«Вашингтона»\xa0Александр Овечкин\xa0забросил\xa0шайбу, а также забил победный буллит в серии в матче с «Баффало» (4:3 Б) и был признан третьей звездой.', 'url': 'https://www.sports.ru/hockey/1107860736-ovechkin-zabil-771-j-gol-v-nxl-do-xou-30-shajb.html', 'urlToImage': 'https://www.sports.ru/dynamic_images/news/110/786/073/6/share/c9cb18.jpg', 'publishedAt': '2022-03-26T01:56:15Z', 'content': None}
```

Here the result is a simple `dict`.